# Tensorflow: How does gen_nn_ops.max_pool_grad_v2() work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a project where I need deconvolution. I read that `gen_nn_ops.max_pool_grad_v2()` can do that. I load the function from `tensorflow.python.ops`.

As far as I understand, the function takes an input and output tensor where the input is a convolutional layer before max pooling and the output the result of the max pooling operation. But what is `grad`? And what exactly does the output of the function represent?

```
ksize = [1,2,2,1]
strides = [1,2,2,1]
padding = 'SAME'
u = gen_nn_ops.max_pool_grad_v2(input, output, grad, ksize, strides, padding)
```

Unfortunately I did not find anything useful on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding deconvolution, `max_pool_grad_v2` is probably not the op you're looking for. For deconvolution, you probably want to use the keras layer [Conv2DTranspose](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2DTranspose) instead.

`max_pool_grad_v2` is a gradient function for computing the gradient of the maxpooling function (you'll see that it's used for that very purpose [internally within tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py#L612)). A gradient function such as `_MaxPoolGradGrad` computes gradients with respect to the ops' inputs given gradients with respect to the ops' outputs. You don't really need to understand *how* gradients are implemented in tensorflow in order to use tensorflow unless you wanted to implement some of your own, but if you did, there is a [guide on the main tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#implement_the_gradient_in_python).